# Window security pins to pull hinge tight

Tags: windows

Do there exist such pins or bolts that are cone or mushroom in shape that, when a window or door is shut, the cones push on the side of the receiving hole and cause a slight pushing force to cause the window or door to close tighter?

[image]

Perhaps similar to these, but I'm aware these are anti-jemmy devices.

[enter link description here](https://windowwaremedia-6ae0.kxcdn.com/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/8/o8LswYTv.jpg)

We have an issue with our upstairs double glazing where, although the seals are OK, the windows can't easily be adjusted and need a tiny amount of movement on the hinge side to pull the window in and make the seal even better.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you basically asking for spring hinges? What type of windows are we talking about?

Comment: @isherwood - no, kind of like SAC or hinge protection bolts that can be used to aid a uPVC window close even more tightly against the seal when the window is shut. Similar to https://windowwaremedia-6ae0.kxcdn.com/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/8/o8LswYTv.jpg bit I'm pretty sure these are for security to do the hinge being the weakest point of failure.

Comment: Can you add a picture?  Where, exactly, is the hinge (like a casement window, or a window sash that tilts for cleaning)?  Are you trying to tighten sashes against each other or tighten the window to the frame?  What part do you envision moving to make things tighter?  Can you accomplish the result with additional weather stripping of some form?

Comment: I think I'm going to just change the hinges and get deeper seals...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a window component that holds the hinge side of a casement tight and it's typically found on the exterior side of the sash when it is closed.

The component is called a [snubber](https://durabuiltwindows.com/glossary/snubber/) (different from an anti-jemming) and can either be made of PVC or Aluminum to match the exterior finish of the window. [(Additional link 1)](https://www.truth.com/products/Hinged-Window-Hardware/Hinges/Snubbers)

[image]___[image]

Though snubbers are intended to prevent [bowing (see item description)](http://www.allaboutdoors.com/Products/Window-Misc-Parts/Window-Snubber-Concealed-Frame-Sash-Mount-sash-anti-bow) of an outswing-casement, they can also be used to ensure that the sash is close to the frame when closed. However, snubbers are not the only elements that help the sash seal better. The weatherstripping and the casement hardware also determine how tight it is and you can contact the window's Service Technician to adjust the operator arms/hardware of the casement sash without having to replace either/both the weatherstrip or hardware.

Though, depending on what kind of operator handle you have, you can remove the handle and reattach it at a slightly rotated position from where it originally was. However, ***please do this at your own discretion*** as over-tightening the sash can cause issues related to the performance of the casement and/or damage the operator hardware if the seal is too tight.

**Note:** The operator handle solution below is only applicable to crank-out style casements. If the window you have is a Euro-style (turn and/or tilt with handle) contacting a Service Technician for adjustments is recommended.
*(Pictures of your window are needed to better address the sealing issues you have with it.)*

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQc2u.jpg): [image]
  [2]: [image]
  [3]: [image]
  [4]: [image]

**[Update]** In the event of your window being a Euro-styled window, with a multipoint locking system, you would need to adjust/re-calibrate the Compression Strikers, Turn[/tilt] Strikers, and Lift Mishandling Device(s) attached to the inside perimeter of the *frame*. Without proper training or tools, however, maintaining consistent alignment on all four sides of the sash can be difficult and may compromise the weatherseal of the window.

[image]___[image]

Hinge Wedges

A final solution are hinge wedges/pull in blocks.

[image]

They work almost identically to the snubbers at the top, however these wedges are concealed within the sash/frame void and slide against each other to "pull in" the sash.

Comment: this seems to be the best answer I'm going to get.... We don't have the crank or Euro windows that have the adjusters. These windows have the handle and a plastic wedge that tightens the handle side to the seal, however the hinge side is under the control of the friction mechanism. I've bought new friction mechanisms and am yet to fit them. I've also replaced the seal on the sash which has made a marked improvement, however some warping over the years still leaves a slight gap (smaller than previously), but still noticeable. The snubbers seem like they could an excellent idea...

Comment: Our front door is Euro/multi-point and has the adjusters you mention, so I'm aware of these :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with the friction system right now but the snubbers should help assist the mechanism when closing at the very least. I would recommend using 1 snubber if the casement is 55" or shorter (center of the sash). Taller: 2 snubbers. Note that the snubbers may displace a small section of the weatherstrip (where the two contact each other) upon closing the sash (see example pic I took above). As an aside, should I find detailed information on the friction system, I will update my answer to hopefully help you out :>

Comment: The friction mechanism is the actual metal mechanism that allows the window to open instead of am actual hinge like a door. These snubbers/wedges is exactly what I'm after. You can get wedges that push against one another and the sliding of the wedges causes the sash to tighten. Some are concealed in the hinge space. Beautiful.

Comment: I got'cha! So, if not exact, it's very much like the operator arms of a crank operated casement. I'll follow up on this in a short while to double-check the comparison of the two to make sure my claim is accurate or not.

Comment: The operator arms of a crank change the mechanism angle so, if you like, they do pretty much the same. I didn't know that the metal "arrow" of the friction mechanism nearest the very corner of the frame is supposed to work very similarly to a wedge, guiding the mechanism into the corner and creating a "tightening" motion. I feel the wedges would provide a much better solution as they would provide a force across more length of the sash and frame.